# SQL CTE vs View

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a transaction table with 65,000,000 rows.

it's divided into about a couple hundred Companies, and each Company is divided into a couple hundred or thousand unique Users.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTransaction]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [LogDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Key1] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

For a specific company I need to get all users and the key value at the user's minimum `LogDateTime` and at the user's maximum `LogDateTime`.

I want to do it this way:

```
;with cteGetMin as
(
    select 
        CompanyId
        , UserId
        , LogDateTime
        , Key1
        , Row_Number() over (partition by UserId order by LogDateTime) as rowNumMin
    from [dbo].[TestTransaction]
    where CompanyId = @companyId
)
,cteGetMax as
(
    select 
        CompanyId
        , UserId
        , LogDateTime
        , Key1
        , Row_Number() over (partition by UserId order by LogDateTime desc) as rowNumMax
    from [dbo].[TestTransaction]
    where CompanyId = @companyId
)
select 
    ma.CompanyId
    ,ma.UserId
    ,ma.Key1 as MaxKey
    ,ma.LogDateTime as MaxLogDateTime
    ,mi.Key1 as MinKey
    ,mi.LogDateTime as MinLogDateTime
from cteGetMax ma
join cteGetMin mi
    on mi.CompanyId = ma.CompanyId
    and mi.userId = ma.userId
    and mi.rowNumMin = 1
    and ma.rowNumMax = 1
```

I could break out each CTE as a separate view (or indexed view?) but the views would be operating on the entire table of 65,000,000 rows.

My first thought is that adding the `WHERE` clause to each CTE will limit the sub results thus improving the performance.

Any thoughts? Should I keep the CTE's, or go with the separate views?

EDIT:  The point I was trying to make is, is it more efficient to have a limiting WHERE clause in a sub-query or in a CTE, or is it more efficient to have a view that operated over the entire 65,000,000 rows?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using:  SQL 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need two subqueries and a join. Instead, you can enumerate the rows both ways with `row_number()`, and then filter once, and do conditional aggregation:

```
select CompanyId, UserId,
    max(case when rowNumMax = 1 then Key1 end) as MaxKey,
    max(LogDateTime)                           as MaxLogDateTime,
    min(case when rowNumMin = 1 then Key1 end) as MinKey,
    min(LogDateTime)                           as MinLogDateTime
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by UserId order by LogDateTime) as rowNumMin,
        row_number() over (partition by UserId order by LogDateTime desc) as rowNumMax
    from [dbo].[TestTransaction] t
    where CompanyId = @companyId
) t
where 1 in (rowNumMin, rowNumMax)
group by CompanyId, UserId
```